# Browse photos on a network drive and delete bad photos

Tags: lenovo, disk-drive

While travelling I put photos from the SD Card onto a networked drive. I can use ES File Explorer to view the photos. However there does not appear to be an option to delete the photos from the full screen view.

Is there an app that allows deleting photos on a network drive from a **full view** of the photo?

Appreciate your help.

Android 6.01 on a Lenovo Yoga tab.

Answer (score 0):

[Ghost Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghostsq.commander&hl=en) has this functionality.

(OK, it's not 100% full screen, there is a little menu space showing at the top and bottom - see screen shot)

Depending on your setup, you might need the [SMB plugin for Ghost Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghostsq.commander.samba&hl=en) to get to your network drive.

[image]

Comment: I tried Ghost Commander. Unfortunately this app says File too big - therefore not suitable for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

After checking many apps I found Photo Mate R3. From my limited testing, it appears to do what I want to achieve. I can access the network drive and view the photos and delete them. A bonus is that the app allows deleting the RAW and JPG versions of the same photo with 1 click. Very Happy. Will buy the app.